# Programmatically scroll to an item of CustomScrollView on Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, scroll, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

I’m trying to create a custom widget in flutter composed of two scrollable items next to each other. The one on the right contains the main data separated into different sections (same List, i used a sticky header for the section header containing the title), the one on the left contains the sections (or shortcuts) of the right one. For example, if I press on the third item of the left List, I would be automatically scrolled down to the third section of the right List. The items don’t have the same height.
Here’s a video that shows what I’m looking for.
[This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3GTf.gif)

I used a a CustomScrollView and imported a sticky header library but I didn't find a way to programmatically scroll to any of them.
any help please?

I found the sticky header library here:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header